# How to segment unstructured text data in python(pandas) for parsing?

Tags: python, pandas, phone-number, text-extraction

The incoming dataframe consists of companies and phone numbers.

The problem is the phone numbers column contains unstructered text.

The lines below represent the examples of the 'Representation' row values

```
(7777) 11-11-11
11-11-11    
87777777777
77776 11111 
11-1-11, 11-1-11    
8 777 777 77 77 (John)  
8 777 777 77 77, 11-11-11
87777777777 87777777777 
8777 7777777 87777777777
11-11-11/111111 
8777 7777777 87777777777
```

etc..

I understand there is no universal regexp to parse this text

**Is it possible to segment this data to the most parsable groups?**

I have tried to group phones by the string length of the values

```
df['CharCount'] = df['Representation'].str.len()  # Representation - is a Phone numbers column
plot_df_CharRepr = df[['CharCount','Representation']].groupby(["CharCount"]).count().sort_values(by='Representation',ascending=False)
```

And I got 96 groups out of 6300 rows

the top ten of groups looks like this

```
CharCount Representation    
15        2197
8         1115
11        830
25        252
16        207
10        189
31        131
32        127
13        105
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "most parsable groups"?

Comment: The perfect case when I use only one function to extract phones from the group

Comment: One group = One method to extract phone numbers from this group

Comment: eg I  somehow made a group of rows

1 row - (7777) 11-11-11
 
2 row - (2222) 22-22-22
 
3 row - (5555) 33-33-33


I can extract phones using one simple algorithm but if won't be applicable to other groups.

so I am interested in the least number of  functions to extract data

Comment: forgot to mention @thushv89